# Multi-Cluster Kubernetes NetworkPolicy

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-networkpolicy, servicemesh

Suppose, I have several Kubernetes clusters and I have some namespaces in each of them.

Some of these namespaces are labeled `project: a` and others `project: b`.

Now I want to ensure that resources in namespaces labeled `project: a` can communicate with each other, but not with something else, same for the other projects.

If it was just one Kubernetes cluster, then I would simply use NetworkPolicies.

However, I would like to connect the clusters somehow and to ensure that this restriction applies also when the resources are spread in many clusters.

Answer (score 1):

Network policies are bound to the local cluster and don't work across clusters for now.